# Determine tangent based on initial tangent and curvature

Tags: line, geometry

I'm having the following scenario :

- 2 points, A and B are on a circle
- curvature of the circle, ***c*** (and hence its ***radius*** = 1/***c***) is known
- the tangent to the circle at point A, ***mA*** is known.
- the direct distance from A to B, ***dAB*** is known
- the arc distance **dAB_arc** is known
- the sector angle between A and B, ***theta*** is known

I'm trying to deduct the tangent at point B, ***mB***. Could anyone please help out ? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is mA - vector, line, or something else?

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is a mathematical question, not a programming one.

Comment: Hey MBo, mA is as described, the tangent to the circle at point A. It's the slope of a line according to the tangent definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If mA is slope of tangent (angular coefficient k in equation like y=kx+b), then

```
mB = tg(arctg(ma)+theta) = (mA + tg(theta))/(1-mA*tg(theta))
```